# how can i set an id like attribute in a document firebase before to insert

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

how can i set an id like attribute in a document firebase before to insert in an angular

```
insertaEquipo(equipo: Equipo) {


    this.db.collection("equipos").add({
      nombre: equipo.nombre,
      url: equipo.url
    })
      .then(function (docRef) {
        console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);

        

      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
      })

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use set instead of add.

**Difference between `set()` and `add()` :**

Set :

When you use `set()` to create a document, you must specify an ID for the document to create.

Add :

By using `add()` Cloud Firestore auto-generate an ID for you.

```
const newDoc = this.db.collection("equipos").doc();
const docId = newDoc.id;
this.db.collection("equipos").doc(docId).set({
    nombre: equipo.nombre,
    url: equipo.url,
    id: docId,
})
.then(function (docRef) {
    console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
})
```